# Dollar Amounts in C#

Tags: c#, string-formatting, currency

I looked through some other posts but nothing seemed to help. So what I'm trying to get is a code that reads out the current balance, with the phrase in front of it, with a dollar amount. Instead of printing the dollar sign its printing `{0:C}`. Am I using `{0:C}` incorrectly?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double TotalAmount;
            TotalAmount = 300.7 + 75.60;
            string YourBalance = "Your account currently contains this much money: {0:C} " + TotalAmount;
            Console.WriteLine(YourBalance);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
string YourBalance = 
    string.Format("Your account currently contains this much money: {0:C} ",TotalAmount);
```

or using string interpolation with C# 6.0+

```
string YourBalance = $"Your account currently contains this much money: {TotalAmount:C} ";
```

Comment: If you don't need to capture the string, but just plan to output it straight to the console, you can also use `Console.WriteLine("Your account currently contains this much money: {0:C} ", TotalAmount);`

Comment: I tried the first one, it tells me "; expected" and "Method name expected" on YourBalance and "Cannot convert method group 'Format' to non delegate type 'string'. Did you intend to invoke the method?" on .Format

Comment: Oh I didn't think about that, I don't need the string to be kept, just output. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

> Am I using {0:C} incorrectly?

Yes you are. You are just concatenating the string and `TotalAmount`. Hence even you used the currency format specifier (`{0:C}`), the currency amount wasn't replacing the specifier.

You need to use [`String.Format()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), like so:

```
string YourBalance = String.Format("Your account currently contains this much money: {0:C}", TotalAmount);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're very close! You need to use `string.Format()`:

```
string YourBalance = string.Format(
    "Your account currently contains this much money: {0:C} ", TotalAmount);
```

The `{0:C}` syntax doesn't mean anything outside of the context of the [Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Here's a working fiddle from your example: [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SbtJ09)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this...

```
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
            double TotalAmount;
            TotalAmount = 300.7 + 75.60;
            string YourBalance = "Your account currently contains this much money: " +
                           string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:C}",TotalAmount);
            Console.WriteLine(YourBalance);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```