# Currency format to get ₹ when use String.Format("{0:C}",45) this code

Tags: c#, winforms

Currency format to get  ₹ when use String.Format("{0:C}",45) this code.

Can anyone tell why get like this?

[image]

Actually, I want $ symbols with the given value.

Comment: What country do you live in? Is it India?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/39909304/34092 help?

Answer (score 2):

That code uses the default culture for the current thread - which is probably your system's default culture.

You have options of:

- Changing the thread's current culture (e.g. with [`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture))
- Specifying a culture explicitly in the `string.Format` call, before the format string

So for example:

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        var value = string.Format(culture, "{0:C}", 45);
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: once culture changes, it works expected things, but how to get $ without set culture in string.format any further setting?

Comment: @sarana: Well yes, as I said in the answer, you can change the current thread's using `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`.